# create module that load index.php

Tags: redirection

I have a php code written in `index.php` that contain a form with method post.

It also read from an external database and fill a table.
To load this form I created a `.module` file with 2 functions `_menu` and `_block`, but I am not able to load the form `(index.php)`
I need to load the form and to open it in the main content of the drupal page
i used :

```
header("location
drupal_goto(
$external_link
```

but nothing is going right and it open in new blank page not in the main content like i want.

please it is urgent
any help

Answer (score 4):

**The Drupal way**

In Drupal we create similar form like this:

**Create a custom module**

- Create a file sites/all/modules/own/form_test/**form_test.info** with this in it:

  name = form_test
  description = form_test
  core = 7.x
  package = Own
- Create a file sites/all/modules/own/form_test/**form_test.module**

(start it with `<?php` tag, but don't add ending ?> tag)

**Write these functions** in your module:

```
function form_test_menu() {
  $items['formtest'] = array(
    'title' => 'Form Test',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('form_test_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
  return $items;
}
```

**An explanation**

**form_test_menu** 
creates a menu item in your navigation menu so we can have a place where to show our custom form. You can think that menu address referring to a page yoursite/**formtest**.

**title**

Title of the page.

**page callback**

Calls a function drupal_get_form which returns a render array for drupal_render().

**page arguments**

Here we pass our custom render array (which form_test_form returns) as an argument for drupal_get_form.

**access callback**

We define it TRUE so that everyone can access this page.

(**Rendering** means turning a structured array into HTML.)

```
function form_test_form($form,&$form_submit) {
  $form['firstname'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Firstname'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['lastname'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Lastname'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    );
  return $form;
}
```

**An explanation**

So we use **render arrays** to describe a form in drupal.

When you use a function to return a render array for drupal_get_form, there are two default parameters that are in use:

**$form**   Holds the form array items we define inside the function when this function is **called again**.

**&$form_submit**   This parameter holds various data items like the **values** you pass when you submit the form.

(Ampersand **&** means that this is a **reference to a variable**, so if we change this variable in this function, changes will show in the parent function too.)

Form items are **added as arrays** to the $form variable. Hash **(#)** sign refers to an attribute of the item.

**Enable the module** in admin/modules

**Flush the caches**

Form can be seen in **yoursite/formtest**, but it doesn't do anything yet.

OR
more links are :

[Drupal 7 - How to Make a Simple Module with a Form and Menu Link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1419390)

[Ten Step-by-Step Code Samples for Learning Form API](https://www.drupal.org/node/262422)

Comment: so i can not load my form i need to re-program the form using drupal function

Comment: @hibanajjar Yes. Drupal implements pretty good form processing with advanced anti-tamper solutions and simply won't cooperate if you ignore them. You can make it, of course, but it's bad idea to try. You won't have your homemade solution as thoroughly tested as Drupal's one is.